# esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set

Tags: proxy, arcgis-js-api

I am attempting to merge the closest facility and driving directions examples together on a website using the arcGIS for javascript (3.17) API.  I have successfully implemented the two on the site separately, so I know my URL and developer.arcGIS accounts are set up correctly, but when combined, they throw the following error:

> esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set

You can see the site (and the code) here: https://mikecp11.github.io/original.html
Any tips on how I can fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the proxyUrl before you start adding the proxy rules.

```
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "https://mikecp11.github.io/PHP/proxy.php";
```

Comment: Do I then need to change the task url's?  If so do you have an example of what they should be switched to?

Comment: @JColl - No, I don't believe you need to change them.

Comment: Minor note: github.io does not support hosting PHP etc. You will not be able to run the resource proxies there.